# Clock with ASCII art

Tags: ascii-art

It is quite simple, any language, make output show the time in the HH:MM or HH:MM:SS while the numbers and the colons being ascii art(The output is ascii art not the program)
Sample output:

```
 ____________      ________     _____       .________ ________
/_   \_____  \  /\ \_____  \   /  |  |  /\  |   ____//  _____/
 |   |/  ____/  \/   _(__  <  /   |  |_ \/  |____  \/   __  \ 
 |   /       \  /\  /       \/    ^   / /\  /       \  |__\  \
 |___\_______ \ \/ /______  /\____   |  \/ /______  /\_____  /
             \/           \/      |__|            \/       \/
```

Bonus points: Add a PM/AM thingy

Bonus points 2: Make it blink 1 time per second(0.5 sec time 0.5 sec no time)

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC! This challenge might benefit from some time in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). As of right now, it's underspecified, lacks an objective scoring criterion, and goes against several less formal community standards, but I feel like this might have potential if we iron out the kinks.

Comment: What should I do? Should I copy paste it into the sandbox and delete it here?

Comment: I... think so? Never actually posted a challenge myself

Comment: I think it could be an interesting challenge, provided that the spec is complete and non-ambiguous. We need to know _exactly_ how to draw all 10 digits and how to draw the digit X followed by the digit Y. (What is the letter-spacing? Is Y always drawn over X, like the '2' over the '1' in your example?) Also, did you create this font? If not, please make sure that you're authorized to post it here.

Comment: You _must_ also include a winning criterion (is this [`code-golf`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info)?) and _should_ probably remove the bonuses, as nobody is going to do that if this is not a strict requirement.